Does Google Family Link control all apps, even those that come from Samsung?
I was told that Samsung has its own browser and other apps, and that Family Link isn't effective on them. I want to be sure I am able to control the usage of their apps on my kid's phone.

I have found that yes, it is possible to control (and block) native Samsung apps using family link.
